# Insertion sort in Python doesn't work

Tags: python, sorting, insertion-sort

I tried this code from this question - [Python insertion sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755568/python-insertion-sort). I modified the code a bit, got rid of the `eval()`.

```
def sort_numbers(s):
    for i in range(1, len(s)):
        val = s[i]
        j = i - 1
        while (j >= 0) and (s[j] > val):
            s[j+1] = s[j]
            j = j - 1
        s[j+1] = val
    print s

x = raw_input("Enter numbers to be sorted: ").split()
sort_numbers(x)
```

It doesn't work for a few too many test cases.

`In: 1001 101 20 24 2000
Out: 1001 101 20 2000 24`

I've also tried with some negative numbers. The code doesn't work. Why is this so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `x` is a List of strings and not integers. You can correct your input example by placing this code before `sort_numbers`:

```
x = [ int(v) for v in x ]
```

**Original result**:

```
Enter numbers to be sorted: 1001 101 20 24 2000
['1001', '101', '20', '2000', '24']
```

**Result after adding that line**:

```
Enter numbers to be sorted: 1001 101 20 24 2000
[20, 24, 101, 1001, 2000]
```

Notice that now the List shown from `print s` does not have elements surrounded by quotes